# decode h264 raw stream using mediacodec

Tags: android, decode, h.264, android-mediacodec

I recieve h264 data from server, I want to  decode this stream using mediacodec and texture view on android.I got the data from the server , parssing it to get the SPS , the PPS and the  video frame data, then I passed this data to the mediacodec , but the function dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 100000) always returns -1 and I get dequeueOutputBuffer timed out.

Any help please, I'am stucked at this issues from three weeks.

this is the code used to decode the video frame.

```
public class H264PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
private TextureView m_surface;// View that contains the Surface Texture

    private H264Provider provider;// Object that connects to our server and gets H264 frames

    private MediaCodec m_codec;// Media decoder

   // private DecodeFramesTask m_frameTask;// AsyncTask that takes H264 frames and uses the decoder to update the Surface Texture
    // the channel used to receive the partner's video
    private ZMQ.Socket subscriber = null;
    private ZMQ.Context context;
    // thread handling the video reception
   // byte[] byte_SPSPPS = null;
    //byte[] byte_Frame = null;
    public static String stringSubscribe=null;
    public static String myIpAcquisition=null;
    public static byte[] byte_SPSPPS = null;
    public static byte[] byte_Frame = null;
    boolean isIframe = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.h264player_activity);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null)
        {
            stringSubscribe=extras.getString("stringSubscribe");
            myIpAcquisition=(extras.getString("myIpAcquisition"));
        }
        // Get a referance to the TextureView in the UI
        m_surface = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);

        // Add this class as a call back so we can catch the events from the Surface Texture
        m_surface.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    // Invoked when a TextureView's SurfaceTexture is ready for use
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        // when the surface is ready, we make a H264 provider Object. When its constructor runs it starts an AsyncTask to log into our server and start getting frames
        provider = new H264Provider(stringSubscribe, myIpAcquisition,byte_SPSPPS,byte_Frame);

    }

    @Override
    // Invoked when the SurfaceTexture's buffers size changed
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    // Invoked when the specified SurfaceTexture is about to be destroyed
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    // Invoked when the specified SurfaceTexture is updated through updateTexImage()
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    }

    private class H264Provider {
        String stringSubscribe = "";
        String myIpAcquisition = "";
        byte[] byte_SPSPPS = null;
        byte[] byte_PPS = null;
        byte[] byte_Frame = null;

        H264Provider(String stringSubscribe, String myIpAcquisition, byte[] byte_SPS, byte[] byte_Frame) {
            this.stringSubscribe = stringSubscribe;
            this.myIpAcquisition = myIpAcquisition;
            this.byte_SPSPPS = byte_SPS;
            this.byte_PPS = byte_PPS;
            this.byte_Frame = byte_Frame;
            System.out.println(" subscriber client started");
            //SetUpConnection setup=new SetUpConnection();
           // setup.execute();
            PlayerThread mPlayer = new PlayerThread();
            mPlayer.start();
        }
        void release(){
            // close ØMQ socket
            subscriber.close();
            //terminate 0MQ context
            context.term();
        }
         byte[] getCSD( ) {
            return byte_SPSPPS;
        }
         byte[] nextFrame(  ) {

            return byte_Frame;
        }
        private class PlayerThread extends Thread
        {

            public PlayerThread()
            {
                System.out.println(" subscriber client started");
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /******************************************ZMQ****************************/
                // Prepare our context and subscriber
                ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
                //create 0MQ socket
                ZMQ.Socket subscriber = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);
                //create outgoing connection from socket
                String address = "tcp://" + myIpAcquisition + ":xxxx";
                Boolean bbbb = subscriber.connect(address);
                subscriber.setHWM(20);//  the number of messages to queue.
                Log.e("zmq_tag", "connect connect " + bbbb);
                //boolean bbbb = subscriber.setSocketOpt(zmq.ZMQ.ZMQ_SNDHWM, 1);
                subscriber.subscribe(stringSubscribe.getBytes(ZMQ.CHARSET));
                Log.e("zmq_tag", " zmq stringSubscribe " + stringSubscribe);
                boolean bRun = true;

                while (bRun) {
                    ZMsg msg = ZMsg.recvMsg(subscriber);
                    String string_SPS = null;
                    String string_PPS = null;
                    String SPSPPS = null;
                    String string_Frame = null;
                    if (msg != null) {

                        // create a video message out of the zmq message
                        VideoMessage oVideoMsg = VideoMessage.fromZMsg(msg);
                        // wait until get Iframe
                        String szInfoPublisher = new String(oVideoMsg.szInfoPublisher);
                        Log.e("zmq_tag", "szInfoPublisher   " + szInfoPublisher);
                        if (szInfoPublisher.contains("0000000167")) {
                            isIframe = true;
                            String[] split_IFrame = szInfoPublisher.split("0000000165");
                            String SPS__PPS =  split_IFrame[0];
                            String [] split_SPSPPS=SPS__PPS.split("0000000167");
                            SPSPPS="0000000167" + split_SPSPPS[1];
                            Log.e("zmq_tag", "SPS+PPS  " + SPSPPS);
                            String iFrame = "0000000165" + split_IFrame[1];
                            Log.e("zmq_tag", "IFrame  " + iFrame);
                            string_Frame = iFrame;
                        } else {
                            if ((szInfoPublisher.contains("0000000161")||szInfoPublisher.contains("0000000141")) && isIframe) {
                                if (szInfoPublisher.contains("0000000161"))
                                {
                                    String[] split_IFrame = szInfoPublisher.split("0000000161");
                                    String newMSG = "0000000161" + split_IFrame[1];
                                    Log.e("zmq_tag", " P Frame  " + newMSG);
                                    string_Frame = newMSG;
                                } else
                                if (szInfoPublisher.contains("0000000141"))
                                {
                                    String[] split_IFrame = szInfoPublisher.split("0000000141");
                                    String newMSG = "0000000141" + split_IFrame[1];
                                    Log.e("zmq_tag", " P Frame  " + newMSG);
                                    string_Frame = newMSG;
                                }

                            } else {
                                isIframe = false;
                            }

                        }


                    }
                    if (SPSPPS != null) {
                        byte_SPSPPS = SPSPPS.getBytes();
                        Log.e("zmq_tag", " byte_SPSPPS  " + new String(byte_SPSPPS));
                    }
                    if (string_Frame != null) {
                        byte_Frame = string_Frame.getBytes();
                        Log.e("zmq_tag", " byte_Frame  " + new String(byte_Frame));
                    }

                    if(SPSPPS != null) {

                        // Create the format settinsg for the MediaCodec
                        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC, 1920, 1080);// MIMETYPE: a two-part identifier for file formats and format contents

                        // Set the PPS and SPS frame
                        format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(byte_SPSPPS));
                        // Set the buffer size
                        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 100000);

                        try {
                            // Get an instance of MediaCodec and give it its Mime type
                            m_codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);
                            // Configure the Codec
                            m_codec.configure(format, new Surface(m_surface.getSurfaceTexture()), null, 0);
                            // Start the codec
                            m_codec.start();
                            // Create the AsyncTask to get the frames and decode them using the Codec
                            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                                // Get the next frame
                                byte[] frame = byte_Frame;
                                Log.e("zmq_tag", " frame  " + new String(frame));
                                // Now we need to give it to the Codec to decode into the surface
                                // Get the input buffer from the decoder
                                int inputIndex = m_codec.dequeueInputBuffer(1);// Pass in -1 here as in this example we don't have a playback time reference
                                Log.e("zmq_tag", "inputIndex  " + inputIndex);
                                // If  the buffer number is valid use the buffer with that index
                                if (inputIndex >= 0) {
                                    ByteBuffer buffer =m_codec.getInputBuffer(inputIndex);
                                    buffer.put(frame);
                                    // tell the decoder to process the frame
                                    m_codec.queueInputBuffer(inputIndex, 0, frame.length, 0, 0);
                                }

                                MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                                int outputIndex = m_codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 100000);
                                Log.e("zmq_tag", "outputIndex  " + outputIndex);
                                if (outputIndex >= 0) {
                                    m_codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputIndex, true);
                                }
                                // wait for the next frame to be ready, our server makes a frame every 250ms
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(250);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // close ØMQ socket
                subscriber.close();
                //terminate 0MQ context
                context.term();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry I can't comment, but I see some probable mistakes in your code :

- Your KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE is wrong, it must be at least your Height * Width, in your case the Height * Width = 1920 * 1080 = 2073600 > 100000, you feed your decoder input buffer with data that can be > 100000, so since the decoder wants NALUs it probably wouldn't like it.
- You do not clear input buffer before pushing data (realy needed?)